# Proper use of "Delete all existing files prior to publish" option

Tags: visual-studio, publishing

When publishing a Visual Studio 2012 MVC website, there is the option to "Delete all existing files prior to publish".  I've had this checked when publishing my websites, which I do over the File System, but this takes the web down until the publish is done.  I'm wondering what are the situations where this option should be turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had situations where not all files that changed were being updated and the old files were being kept. Although I still don't know why that happened, let Visual Studio delete this files helped. Still, I will never save/activate this option in one of my profiles. Use it with care, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation in a MVC project where I moved a view file to the Shared folder.  When I did a publish without doing a delete all, it left that file in the original folder.  When I called the Controller method that referenced that view on the live site, it found the view file in the original folder before the one in the Shared folder.  Doing a delete all first would have kept that problem from happening.